# Using Comparative Operators to find local maxima in column of data frame

Tags: python-3.x, compare, max

I have an excel file where each column represents successive time periods. I want to determine the local maxima for each time period (i.e., within each column). This is the code I have thus far:

```
    import pandas as pd  
    df = pd.read_excel('my_sheet.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')   

    b = df['time_period_1'] 

    i = 1  
    for i in b:  
        if b[i] > b[i-1] and b[i] > b[i+1]:  
            print(b[i]) 
        i=i+1
```

Which gives the error

```
    KeyError: 24223
```

24223 is the first value in the column
Any idea what is going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you are using "i" for both the increment inside of the loop and as an element of b. Basically "for i in b" puts the first value of "b" in "i", which is "24223" but this key is incorrect as certainly your column does not contain 24223 elements.

Basically, change the name of one of your index. For instance :

```
k = 1  
for i in b:  
    if i > b[k-1] and i > b[k+1]:  
        print(b[k]) 
    k += 1
```

(not sure here if you want to print(b[k]) or print(i), but you'll get the point)

**Edit 1:** you should use "i" as an object in "b", as you don't need it to be an index. When you use "for i in b", i is already the content of the cell. Use "b[i]" only when i is an index. So here, you either :

```
for i in range(len(b)) :
  if b[i] > ...
```

where i is an index, or :

```
for i in b :
   if i > ...
```

where i is an object.

**Edit 2:** to avoid accessing b[k+1] for the last index (which triggers an error as k+1 does not exist), use an if-condition. Also for clarity purposes, I would recommand using only one index. Note that to acheive this you also need a condition for the first row, as b[-1] would refer to the last row in python and I assume it is not what you want the first row to be compared to. Here is a code that should work:

```
for i in range(len(b)):           #range begins implicitly at 0
   if i > 0 and i < len(b)-1:     #so you are not on the first nor last row
      if b[i] > b[i-1] and b[i] > b[i+1]:
         print(b[i])
   elif i==0:        #first row, to be compared with the following one only
      if b[i] > b[i+1]:
         print(b[i])
   else:            #last row, to be compared with the previous one only
      if b[i] > b[i-1]:
         print(b[i])
```

There would be mode concise and elegant ways to do so, but I think this one is the clearest.

Comment: Thank you! I gave this a try, and instead I got KeyError: 100, with 100 being the number of values in the column. Any idea why this would be the case? I'm brand new to data frames, so I apologize if this should be straightforward.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone was a beginner at some point ;) There is an index problem from the very last row (k=100 for you as you say) : you try to compare b[i] with the following row b[101] which does not exist. It can be easily solved but it depends on what you are willing to do : do you want to compare the last row with the first one ? Or only with the previous one ?

Comment: I would want to compare the last one only with the previous one. I tried nesting the for loop within a  while loop:  k = 1 , while k < len(b): ,  for i in b: etc., but I am still getting KeyError:100. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is normal that you get the same error, as you are still trying to access the last+1 row which does not exist when you do b[k+1].

I'll edit my post with a code that should work.